# Flutter: Unable to load asset file

Tags: flutter, assets

I have  added my assets into my projects directory also did everything on `pubspec.yaml` but I am still getting the Unable to load asset.

I also tried giving a specific path (like `- assets/image/x.png`) in pubspec, but nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong?

I used it like this

[image: I used it like this]

`pubspec.yaml`

[image: pubspec]

assets folder

[image: assets folder]

Comment: @Manishyadav Please stop suggesting edits that add `code formatting` to things that aren't actually code. Please read [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i forgot to put a - before family: Roboto. Just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

@vinternal just stop and run app again.

Comment: i tried it, also tried flutter clean nothing changed. Still getting the same error.

Comment: have you set the height and width for that container.

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully follow the structure:

1. Hey put the assets folder in root folder, I think you have put it under lib folder.
2. Intendation(space) before the -asset/images in pubspec.yaml should not be changed otherwise it may have issue